# NullPointerException while indexing variable String parameters

Tags: java, string, variables, parameters, nullpointerexception

I'm new to the idea of using an ellipsis. I'm almost certain my error is caused by improperly declaring or initializing "`String[] authors`", but I don't know how to do this an still have my `setAuthors` method work.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Book {
    private String[] authors; //I'm guessing this line should end with "= new String..."
                              //but not sure how to w/o specifying an array dimension
    private int authorsSize;

    //Receives variable # of String parameters and indices them into String[] "authors"
    public void setAuthors(String... authors) {
        authorsSize = authors.length;
        for(int i=0;i<authorsSize;i++)
            this.authors[i] = authors[i];
    }
```

//getAuthors method:

```
    public String getAuthors(){
         String s = "";
         authorsSize = authors.length;
              for(int i=0;i<authorsSize;i++)
              s = s+authors[i] + ", ";
         printAuthors = s;
         return s;
    }
```

Comment: getAuthors method:

public String getAuthors(){
     String s = "";
     authorsSize = authors.length;
     for(int i=0;i<authorsSize;i++)
          s = s+authors[i];
     printAuthors = s;
     return s;
}

Comment: You need to cater for authors being null in your get method... Also, what is printAuthors?

Comment: I have now added an adjusted getAuthors method in my answer below. I've taken the liberty of improving it by having comma's only between elements and also by using the more efficient StringBuilder

Answer (score 7):

The *simplest* approach would just be to clone the array:

```
public void setAuthors(String... authors){
    this.authors = (String[]) authors.clone();
}
```

After all, you're overwriting the previous data anyway, and you can't know the size before the method call. You don't need the `authorsSize` variable at this point - you've got the `authors` array which knows its own length.

(If you were able to use immutable collections, you wouldn't even need to bother cloning, of course.)

EDIT: As noted in comments, this method will throw an exception if you pass in a null reference. You *shouldn't* automatically decide that this is a situation you should "handle" - it's entirely legitimate to document that the parameter must not be null. I would suggest documenting the behaviour around nullity *either way*.

Indeed, if you do this you might *also* want to initialize your instance field like this:

```
private String[] authors = new String[0];
```

That way you always know you'll have a non-null reference in that field, so you can use it with impunity. I would prefer this over having to check for null on every use.

Comment: What is the null is passed as an argument ? Your code will throw `NullPointerException` and it will fail. For more info check my code below.

Comment: What if the NULL is passed then exception will be thrown and the previous values will be unchanged to the old values. rather it should be set null.

Comment: @BhavikAmbani: If it throws a NullPointerException, that's quite possibly the correct behaviour - we don't know whether the document is *intended* to handle a null reference.

Comment: @JonSkeet But the old value will be unchanged, rather the old values should be set to null, i.e. this.authors should be set with null as null is passed as authors.

Comment: @BhavikAmbani: If the method has been called incorrectly, the state of the class *shouldn't* be changed. That's general best practice. See my edit - explicitly declaring that `null` is an invalid parameter value seems like it's more likely to be a good thing, IMO.

Comment: @JonSkeet null can and does get used as a valid value. I guess its up to the person writing the code to decide they don't want nulls... IMO it's best to let calling code decide whether or not nulls are acceptable as this lets different calling code reuse the method for different circumstances...

Comment: @Brian: It can and is used in some cases - and in some cases it's not.  But it shouldn't be up to the calling code - it should be up to the class to publish how it will handle nulls. Then it's a single point of truth - otherwise you get the situation where one class populates an object, and another uses it - and they disagree on what's valid. For collections, I *usually* find that allowing empty collections but prohibiting null is more useful than allowing null and then usually treating it the same was as empty.

Comment: @JonSkeet fair enough on the point that collections can be empty so null is normally a problem with them, no matter what the circumstance. (:

Answer (score 3):

you never initialized `authors` your array . 
you need to initialize it before you use it .

```
String[] authors = new String[size];
```

> //but not sure how to w/o specifying an array dimension

The best way is to use an List implementing classes as they are dynamic Arrays. i.e., you dont need to specify the size.

```
List<String> authors = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to currect your `setAuthors` method as described below

```
public void setAuthors(String... authors) {
    if (authors != null && authors.length > 0) {
        authorsSize = authors.length;
        authors = new String[authorsSize];
        for (int i = 0; i < authorsSize; i++)
            this.authors[i] = authors[i];
    }else{
        this.authors = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well done on checking null and length, but the problem is that this.authors will not change if the authors is null or 0 and will hold onto old data...

Comment: Slightly different outcome to mine below, depending on what you want to happen in the case of a null or 0

Comment: As I said please find my updated answer, where I checked null or 0 value

Comment: yes, I found your updated answer, I was just pointing out that the eventual outcome of this.authors would be different between our 2 code snippets as you would make this.authors = null and I would make this.authors = new String[]

Comment: I have now changed mine to be probably the most correct version... If authors is null, set this.authors = null. otherwise continue (even if authors.length <= 0)

Comment: @Brian Move on to another questions. This question is over and move on to another questions, don't just spend your entire day on a single question's answer.

Comment: I can spend as long as I like, on whatever I like... Especially if I feel there is more to be added.

Comment: @BhavikAmbani Your code doesn't work when I compile it, I still get a NullPointerException. Although, if I replace line 4 with "this.authors = new String[authorsSize];" it compiles, but returns null instead of J. R. R. Tolkien. This is probably because my getAuthors method (added above) is faulty. Jon Skeet's code does the same thing for me.

Answer (score 1):

Because the declaration of "private String[] authors" is before that of "public void setAuthors(String... authors)", you can not use the format like "String[] authors = new String[authorsSize]".  This will make the size of authors always be 0.

The better way is to use the dynamic initialization:
List authors = new ArrayList();
Then use this.authors.add(authors[i]) to pass parameters.

Answer (score 0):

you could also adjust your code like so:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Book{

    private String[] authors; 
    private int authorsSize;

    public void setAuthors(String... authors){

        //check for null, you could also set this.authors = new String[] if you prefer.
        if(authors == null){
            this.authors = null;
        }else{
            authorsSize = authors.length;

            //also add this line...
            this.authors = new String[authorsSize];

            for(int i=0;i<authorsSize;i++)
                this.authors[i] = authors[i];
        }
    }

    public String getAuthors(){
         if(authors == null){
             return ""; //could also return null here if you would prefer
         }

         StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
         authorsSize = authors.length;
         for(int i=0;i<authorsSize;i++){
             if(i > 0)
                 s.append(",");

             s.append(authors[i]);
         }

         //printAuthors = s;
         return s.toString();
    }
}
```